# Bluetooth problem Lenovo-Z50-70 (Atheros QCWB355)

Tags: bluetooth, 14.10, lenovo, atheros

When I got my Lenovo-Z50-70 I directly installed Ubuntu 14.10, the Wifi (Atheros AR9565) worked out of the box. But then I wanted to connect my bluetooth devices it never found any of them.

I looked at `rfkill` nothing was hard of softblocked.

According to Lenovo the BTchip is a Atheros QCWB355 but I can't find any available Linux drivers.

I also looked in my bios if there where any configurations but there was nothing relevant.

Does someone know a where I can get a driver for this or if there is an other problem?

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)  
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)  
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)  
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)  
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)  
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)  
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter    
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller  
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2516:0014  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**hciconfig:**

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB  
    BD Address: 10:08:B1:09:E7:22  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16  
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN   
    RX bytes:1188 acl:0 sco:0 events:68 errors:0  
    TX bytes:1102 acl:0 sco:0 commands:68 errors:0
```

Comment: Please [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/573885/edit) your question with `lspci -nn`, `lsusb` and `hciconfig` output in your terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t)

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth might work after installing these https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/master.zip

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/archive/troy.zip

See [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work)

Comment: I tried it and it now finds devices, the only problem still is that the devices that it finds are of type unknown so it can' t connect and it only displays its address, not its name.

Comment: What type devices are they?  I remember that some devices are not yet supported by the Ubuntu bluetooth stack