# RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work

Tags: bluetooth

I am unable to find any bluetooth devices.

I was able to fix it by using [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), but since the Ubuntu kernel update this fix has stopped working.

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter


3.16.0-34-generic #45~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 24 11:13:52 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You follow similar instructions to when you first installed

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

And for bluetooth

```
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

October 2015 edit, Pilot6 has a PPA with a dkms module that doesn't need to be reinstalled after a kernel update

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```

Reboot and done

Comment: I do this several times and same result do not work

Comment: Bluetooth would also need https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/troy as it isn't supported in any kernel yet or git command would be `git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git`

Comment: You Are Awesome woks finally works!!!!!

Comment: There is an error. it is not "cd rtl8723au_bt-troy", but "cd rtl8723au_bt". Branch does not change directory.

Comment: @Pilot6  At the time, that is the way it worked as I tried the commands on my own laptop.  It has changed since and `cd rtl8723au_bt` is what works now

Comment: Is this only for Realtek? What about `413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth`?

Comment: @Chloe This is just for Realtek.  I think Dell used Broadcom bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt.git
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtk_btusb
```

You should be all set.

NOTE: According to this: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/18 the driver covers all Realtek BT devices.

Comment: I made all as you say.   I download again and made all steps make clean
make
sudo make install
Still not work

Comment: Please see my revised answer above.

Comment: doesn't work on Ubuntu 18

Comment: @Skyrocker Very few 5 1/2 year old answers involving kernel modules still work today as kernel versions, gcc, etc. have rapidly changed. Please start a new question and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I made a ppa with DKMS driver from lwfinger. It builds against all supported Ubuntu kernels. Install it by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms rtl8723au-bt-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: I'm using your ppa, I can see the device with hcitool devices... but when i try to connect with bluez i get "host is down" (I can connect if I use a USB adapter)

Comment: @J.Serra You need also `sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms`. But you will need to remove alternative wireless drivers, if you installed any.

Comment: My bad, I forget to install a package. WiFi and BT are working.

Answer (score 0):

[Jeremy31](https://askubuntu.com/users/300665/jeremy31) answered this in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work/607405#comment850578_607368):

> Bluetooth would also need
>   [github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/troy](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/troy) as it isn't supported
>   in any kernel yet or git command would be `git clone -b troy
>   https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git`

Answer (score 0):

Until now I've spent hours to read in different threads to let my bluetooth work reliable.
I'm using Mint Rafaela 17.2 on a HP 350 G2 with a RTL8723BE device. But for sure you can transfer this workaround to Ubuntu

These things I found out for my notebook:

- Bluetooth works only when OS starts with connected AC power. With battery you will encounter in terminal by entering `hciconfig -a` following output

  ```
  "Can't read local name on hci0: Connection timed out (110)"
  ```
- Sometimes ISCAN is not enabled automatically. So you need a `sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan`. Then retry `hciconfig -a` to check.
- I updated the driver with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware rtl8723au-bt-dkms
  ```

  Did a reboot
- In a terminal I entered:

  ```
  hciconfig -a  # To check first if you have running PISCAN ISCAN.
  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover && pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
  ```

  You should get for both modules a number. In my case 24 and 25.
- If you get an error like

  ```
  module initialisation fails
  ```

  then I did a

  ```
  sudo service bluetooth restart && pulseaudio -k
  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover && pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
  ```

  Now you should get the numbers.
- With `sudo hcitool scan` you should now find your bluetooth device you want to pair. Like: mydevice `08:DF:1F:1F:82:0C`
- Try now to search the device with your bluetooth applet. I installed `blueman`, `bluez-utils` and `bluez-tools`.
- If till now everything worked fine. Congrats. Now you can connect your device and enjoy it.
- I made a script to access to my BT device by shortcut (ex. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).
  My script for my Bose Soundlink - `soundlink.sh` (executable file):

  ```
  service bluetooth restart
  pulseaudio -k
  sleep 10
  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover && pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect 
  bt-audio -c 08:DF:1F:1F:82:0C # you need to change it with the address of your device
  ```

  To disconnect you can make a new shortcut like (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) with the following command:

  ```
  bt-audio -d 08:DF:1F:1F:82:0C #address of your device
  ```

Now everything works fine for me and I hope it can also be helpful for you. 
I'm very happy that I found this thread. Thank you a lot.