# Ubuntu 14.04 Bluetooth problem on Lenovo

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo, realtek

Hej guys,
yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 13. This is the first time that I use Linux, so my experience in using Linux is not the best.
My problem is that my built in bluetooth does not work. When I activate bluetooth in the control panel nothing happen.
Maybe someone can help me?
Thank u!

For:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

I get:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 5986:029c Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

For:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

I get:

```
[    2.666590] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    2.666636] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.667115] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.667119] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.667127] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.689434] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.689437] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.689442] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.708230] Bluetooth: hci0: hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[    2.713806] Bluetooth: RTL8723A: unexpected EPATCH signature!
[    2.741344] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.741354] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.741359] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

after firmware update:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

->

```
[    2.689988] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    2.690009] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.690057] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.690061] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.690067] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.713594] Bluetooth: hci0: hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[    2.726900] Bluetooth: RTL8723A: unexpected EPATCH signature!
[    2.774790] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.774794] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.774799] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.806719] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.806729] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.806744] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and:

```
uname -r
```

->

```
3.19.0-30-generic
```

make ->

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/build M=/home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic« wird betreten
  CC [M]  /home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt/rtk_btusb.o
/home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt/rtk_btusb.c: In function ‘btusb_intr_complete’:
/home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt/rtk_btusb.c:168:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘hci_recv_fragment’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (hci_recv_fragment(hdev, HCI_EVENT_PKT,
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt/rtk_btusb.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bjoern/rtl8723au_bt] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic« wird verlassen
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

and for make install ->

```
mkdir -p /lib/firmware/rtk_bt
cp -f rlt8723a_chip_b_cut_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch-svn8511-0x0020342E-20121105-LINUX_USB.bin /lib/firmware/rtk_bt/rtk8723a.bin
cp -f rtl8723a_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtk_bt/.
cp -f rtk_btusb.ko /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/rtk_btusb.ko
cp: der Aufruf von stat für »rtk_btusb.ko“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make: *** [install] Fehler 1
```

For

```
~/rtl8723au_bt$ ~/rtl8723au_bt$ cd ~/rtl8723au_bt; git checkout master && sudo make install
```

->

```
Bereits auf 'master'
Ihr Branch ist auf dem selben Stand wie 'origin/master'.
mkdir -p /lib/firmware/rtk_bt
cp -f rlt8723a_chip_b_cut_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch-svn8511-0x0020342E-20121105-LINUX_USB.bin /lib/firmware/rtk_bt/rtk8723a.bin
cp -f rtl8723a_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtk_bt/.
cp -f rtk_btusb.ko /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/rtk_btusb.ko
cp: der Aufruf von stat für »rtk_btusb.ko“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make: *** [install] Fehler 1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: ´0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no´

Comment: Please add TO YOUR QUESTION output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: Hold on, I will fix it. The firmware should be updated.

Comment: I added to the answer the firmware update. Please confirm that it works.

Comment: thank u, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Please give the `dmesg | grep -i blue` again. And also `uname -r`.

Comment: Hm. Please add then output of `ls -l /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22172 Okt 11 12:54 /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw
`

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I got some errors for `make` and `make install` (see above).

Comment: Run `cd ~/rtl8723au_bt; git checkout master && sudo make install`.

Comment: The error messages are in german, I hope its not a problem.

Comment: It is not a problem. Next time you can run the commands with `LANG=C` prefix to get them in English. I can't fix it right now, something has changed it the kernel code and it does not build.

Comment: This device should be supported by kernel 4.2 out of the box.

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work) and follow commands under "And for bluetooth", just 4 commands

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it does not work

Comment: Did you try to install bluetooth drivers before from lwfinger github rtl8723au_bt?

Comment: Yes, but only with errors (see above)

Comment: In that case I would `rm -r rtl8723au_bt` then run the commands from my answer linked above