# Bluetooth device not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

My bluetooth does not work at all. I can turn it on in settings but it will not search for devices or turn on visibility.

I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`; `lsusb` and got the result:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Fairly new to ubuntu, are there any other commands I should run to get the help I require to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask how old is your computer and is your computer Bluetooth ready? meaning do you already have the BlueTooth adapters installed on your machine.

What distro of Ubuntu are you currently running on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for a swift response, going to mark this as solved, i went hunting and i found this link and fixed my problem, [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work)

a little premature of me to post a question i know.