# Bluetooth 14.04 on Lenovo H50 - RTL8723BE

Tags: bluetooth, rtl8723be

Referring to a question already answered by Pilot6 in thread [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work)

I recognize the answer there using dkms by Pilot6 but they are somewhat dated. Has this been fixed in updates for 14.04 as of April 2016? I am not able to find bluetooth devices on my Lenovo H50 using the RTL8723BE chip with an updated 14.04 system as of now.

Before I start loading stuff should the advice in the original thread still be followed? If so has there been any changes in directions?

Comment: Mid 2015 isn't dated. If your Bluetooth isn't working, try those solutions. I'm not sure what makes you think it isn't even worth trying.

Comment: There is a package for bluetooth in my repo. It is made for kernels up to 3.19. In kernel 4.2 it is supposed to work by itself. But I never got any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Those answers aren't dated; they're less than a year old. 14.04 is almost two years old. For major changes, Ubuntu gets a new version. The method for something like that would not change within the same version.

If it was a solution for 6.10, then the procedure would likely be different, but it's not. Something I found important in Pilot6's answer:

```
It builds against all supported Ubuntu kernels.
```

It makes me think that it would work everywhere, and that it's kernel-dependent and not OS version dependent.

To sum it up, there is no harm in trying. Nine-ish months is not long enough in my book to rule out answers as invalid. A few years can even be fine. **Try it out! :-)**