# Bluetooth not working on a Lenovo ideapad 100-15iby (Wi-Fi unstable too)

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, laptop, lenovo, 16.04

*I have made edits to this post and Wi-Fi works now, but I still have problems with Bluetooth, and is further explained below at "**EDITS:**"*

*A verbose output of lsusb has been posted down below, please tell me if I can get more info out of this. It indicates that Bluetooth is under Chicony Electronics.*

*Note: I have added another bounty on this question as I still have this issue with Bluetooth. I would like to have my internal Bluetooth working to reduce hassle with USB devices. I recall browsing answers which includes converting and editing specific driver files from Windows so I can use it with Linux and would like to do that where possible, but I lack experience with it and would love an answer that guides me through.*

***Original Question***

I've got everything working on this laptop except for two tiny wee things:

1. Bluetooth is not functioning correctly: it does show up in the tray, I can turn it on. When trying searching for a new device, none is found, and my other devices are unable to find my laptop either.
2. Wi-Fi does seem to work, but after some time this becomes unstable: I'm unable to connect to any access point anymore until I restart my machine.

I have been searching on several forums and on this website, but I honestly do not have any idea what specific model I have for Bluetooth & Wi-Fi, and am unable to determine what drivers I need for this. I do know that the manufacturer of this Bluetooth device is Realtek.

If you would like to help me, I'd gladly appreciate it.

lsusb:

```
reboot@LNV-IDPAD-100-14IBY0:~$ sudo lsusb 
[sudo] password for reboot: 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b49f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174f:1169 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
reboot@LNV-IDPAD-100-14IBY0:~$
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

If any more information is needed, please tell me.
Thanks in advance,

Reboot

**Edits:**

lsusb -v: http://pastebin.com/5Whp5dfv

I have installed the Wi-Fi driver from source from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). I tried to install the Bluetooth driver with [these files](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt) and make, but they do not work. Does anyone know the solution to Bluetooth?

Comment: You can fix Wi-Fi by [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/635629/167850). Regarding BT it should work with this kernel. If not I will look into it.

Comment: There is no BT package for 16.04 in that PPA yet. I am not quite sure it is needed.

Comment: And also I am not sure that there is BT in this laptop at all.

Comment: BT won't work, but Wi-Fi should become stable. I will wright an answer for BT.

Comment: I have added more edits to my question

Comment: You tried to to build from a wrong branch. Download from `kernel` branch, not `master`.

Comment: Excuse me as I still do not understand what you mean: I downloaded the files from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new (button called download as ZIP.) What exactly do I need to download?

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/archive/kernel.zip

Comment: Well I have installed that from source three times (Wi-Fi before of course) after wiping ubuntu completely... Bluetooth does not seem to work at all... I have read the readme file and tried all the steps and installed blueman but even with blueman I can't find anything...

Comment: I think USB and PCI doesn't fall into significance in this case.  Does it?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm sure my Wi-Fi adapter is capable of handling with both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Comment: BT may use USB or PCI to communicate to the system but the actual BT driver may be a different component since it makes no much sense to tie any of the technologies.

Comment: In the readme document of the Github link of Pilot, it said it had to do with a USB Bluetooth dongle.

Comment: I would just like add that regarding wifi instability, you can restart the network service without restarting your computer by doing `sudo service network-manager restart`. I have to do this every couple hours on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: I suggest reporting a bug to Lanchpad. There is a problem with the kernel module. It does not work.

Comment: What model mouse are you trying to get to work?  Some just work better than others.  I got a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort bt mouse to work on an rt8723ae after failing to get a generic bt mouse to work.

Comment: It's not even about just BT mice here, I am trying a variety of different BT devices such as speakers & headsets, smartphones, other computers. Whatever I search for, it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Your `lsusb` does not look full. If you post a full output, I can check if the BT device is detected.

Comment: Please run `lsusb` without `sudo`. Does anything change?

Comment: Here is a pastebin with a verbose lsusb output: http://pastebin.com/5Whp5dfv My bad I didn't think about this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a new mini-PCIe Wi-Fi card (30-50 bucks) if I were you. Lot's of good ones out there. If you want to keep up on the bug reports for your card not working with bluetooth and flaky wifi you can read what others have tried and [sign up here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1382404)

Comment: Thus far your answer turned out to be most helpful during the bounty period, and therefore you deserve to have it. I will consider purchasing a new adapter if the bug continues to prevent me from using Bluetooth. The link you provided to me also allowed me to get a further insight on this bug. Thanks for willing to help.

Comment: @Reboot - my pleasure.

Comment: @Reboot Bumping an old question; did you replace the Wi-Fi card in the end? I heard this might be prevented due to BIOS whitelisting.

Comment: @amees_me I've replaced my card and it's working just perfectly fine for me. Could be because my laptop had FreeDOS on it, so I'm not sure about the OEM Windows 10 versions of the laptop... Chances might be that there is better kernel support for this adapter now but you'd have to upgrade your Linux kernel manually for that.

Comment: @Reboot Interesting! Many Lenovo laptops have BIOS-whitelists preventing you from changing the Wi-Fi card. What card did you change to?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Realtek shows nothing for an RTL8723BE, but the WiFi drivers for Linux can be downloaded directly from Realtek, here: [Realtek PCIe WiFi driver page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=21&Level=4&Conn=3)

Here is an AskUbuntu page which seems to solve the WiFi problem for this Reaktek card: [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

There was an answer which appears to have solved the bluetooth problem in AskUbuntu: [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work)

Those should solve your issue.

Respectfully,
David

Comment: Unfortunately compiling this driver will result in a bunch of errors for me: 
/home/reboot/Documents/makedump/bt/rtl8723au_bt/btusb.c:111:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
And a lot more:
btusb.c:114:12: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘reassembly’
  skb = hdev->reassembly[index];
            ^
btusb.c:141:7: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘reassembly’
   hdev->reassembly[index] = skb;
       ^
btusb.c:163:10: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘reassembly’
      hdev->reassembly[index] = NULL;

Comment: (Comment 2) I have stumbled across http://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work before, though the same compiling error occurred before me posting this question on here.

Comment: Your lsusb result does not show a Realtek usb bluetooth device and is likely why you received USB errors. Here is a discussion which seems to provide a manner to solve the problems some have with it: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/18  But Ubuntu uses an older version of Bluez which causes problems for some. You can download the latest Bluez file here: http://www.bluez.org/download/  But the fact that it doesn't show in your lsusb results is a concern.