# Bluetooth not working, Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 100 15-IBY

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

Bluetooth module is 'working' but doesn't detect any device at all.
I installed https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new, and rtl8723au_bt-kernel
Then i followed Pilot6's instructions in this post: [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work) and finally got everything installed, but still nothing is detected. Maybe i should have uninstalled the first drivers before installing Pilot6's ones? Also i couldn't download rtl8723au-bt-dkms using apt-get, i had to download the .deb from the web and run the installer.
Please help me, i don't know what else to do.

lsusb says:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:3494 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174f:1169 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

hciconfig -a says:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 74:C6:3B:40:E0:50  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1643 acl:0 sco:0 events:149 errors:0
    TX bytes:1607 acl:0 sco:0 commands:136 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ChinaGirl'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

`usb-devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=`

```
T: Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#= 3 Spd=12 MxCh= 0 
D: Ver= 2.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1 
P: Vendor=13d3 ProdID=3494 Rev=02.00 
S: Manufacturer=Realtek 
S: Product=Bluetooth Radio 
S: SerialNumber=00e04c000001 
C: #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA 
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb 
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux ChinaGirl 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance.

here's the bug report i filled:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1616535

Comment: Please post output of `uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: Now I see the BT device and see what is the problem. Please also add output of `usb-devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=` command. I can fix it.

Comment: And also `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Please add output TO YOUR QUESTION, NOT TO COMMENTS. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I do not need full list of `usb-devices`. I edited your question and added it there for you. It is enough. Now please read my answer. If you help, I will fix the issue.

Comment: You also need to remove all 3rd party drivers you installed before. They can conflict.

Comment: how do i remove the other drivers? i'll put my best effort to dive into the linux world! thanks for the work you do bro.

Answer (score 0):

This specific device is not known to Linux kernel yet. But it is not a big problem. I can add it there.

You need to create a bug report by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

in terminal.

Follow directions to create the report and post the output of

```
usb-devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=
```

to the bug description in addition to an explanation of the bug.

When you create the report, post a link to it here.

I will build a test module that should enable bluetooth for you. If it works well, I will send a patch to kernel maintainers and post a workaround here.

Comment: Here's the link to the bug report, i'll add it to the original post as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1616535

Comment: Well done. I will post a module soon.

Comment: launchpad is slow today. it will be built in about an hour.

Comment: See the bug report.

Comment: Thanks Pilot! I just replied the results (very negative) in the bug report. I'll wait for your answer to proceed.