# RTL8723BE Bluetooth not working

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, debian, rtl8723be

RTL8723BE Bluetooth not working. Specifically, the driver cannot be detected at all:

- `hciconfig -a` returns absolutely nothing.
- `hcitool dev` just returns `Devices:` (nothing)

Already tried using the solution in this question: [RTL8723BE Bluetooth does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607339/rtl8723be-bluetooth-does-not-work)

Prior to installing the lwfinger solution, the bluetooth can be turned on but cannot detect other devices.

Before showing the script for the bluetooth driver, here is what I ran for the Wifi driver (from a fresh install):

```
## Wifi driver
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek wireless-tools
## But range is poor so
mkdir ~/git-clones
cd ~/git-clones
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new.git
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
```

#### Approach 1

Now here is what I ran specifically for the bluetooth driver:

```
## Bluetooth driver
cd ~/git-clones
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

#### Approach 2

Also attempted to install the rar file from this link: https://github.com/troy-tan/driver_store/tree/master/bluetooth/8723BE . Unpacked this rar and then `sudo make install -s` as prescribed in the README file. Still nothing happens.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Still didn't find a solution for the bluetooth...

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed with this kernel:

[http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997](http://%20http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997)

as long as you select antenna 1:

```
modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Make sure you have that in config too:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf'
```